# FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response. (storage/unknown)

Tags: javascript, file-upload, next.js, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload a picture from my next.js app to firebase storage. I seem to have done everything as expected but I'm getting a 404 response. I've been trying to figure out the issue but I can't seem to find the right solution. Below is my code examples

`firebase.ts`

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

// Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

`Upload function`

This function is called on button click when the image has already been selected. The image file content exists in `selectedImage` state variable.

```
 const handleUpload = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (selectedImage) {
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${selectedImage.name}`);
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, selectedImage);
      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot: { bytesTransferred: number; totalBytes: number }) => {
          const progress = Math.round(
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          );
          setProgresspercent(progress);
        },
        (error: any) => {
          alert(error);
        },
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL: any) => {
            setUploadedImage(downloadURL);
          });
        }
      );
    }
  };
```

`This is the response I get from Firebase`

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found."
  }
}
```

`This is my firebase storage rules`

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, YES! I've created a default bucket of my Firebase project.